# Windows 7 Batch file to xcopy from "filepath_from.csv" to "filepath_to.csv"

Tags: batch-file, csv, windows-7, xcopy

I'm sure it's been done before but from source destinations listed in a file "filepath_from.csv" with contents like:

```
.\ARCHIVE\FOO.PDF,  
.\ARCHIVE\BAR.PDF
```

To a destination on the corresponding ith line of the file "filepath_to.csv":

```
.\VARYING\PATH\IN\WORKING\DIR\FOO.PDF,  
.\VARYING\PATH\IN\WORKING\DIR\BAR.PDF,
```

How can a Windows 7 batch file copy these files where the destination directory is to be created in the copy command?

Edit: If it simplifies things, I could make the program which generates these two .csv files simply make one .csv file with two columns.

Comment: are these the only columns in the csv files? are they synvhronized well?

Comment: These are the only columns, they are synchronised - every entry has a matching path from and path to.

Comment: @user2727391 Please do not add 'SOLVED' to your question. We already know you got an answer that helped you, that's what the [green check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) in the left margin indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in a bat file and run it.
It reads paths to copy to from filepath_from.csv and copyes each one to path specified in filepath_to.csv. filepath_to.csv is read from application stream3. It avoids interfering with STDIN. filepath_from.csv is read in standard for loop.
I assume both files have equal number of rows.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

3<filepath_from.csv (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (filepath_to.csv) do (
      set line=
      set /P line=<&3
      copy /Y /Z "!line!" "%%a" 
      rem Or use      xcopy "!line!" "%%~dpa" /Y /Z
   )
)
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I actually have the second csv file, but want to do an xcopy command with the paths written in the two csv files (or two columns of one csv file if simpler, as in the question edit)

Comment: You cannot write to a file that is being read now. So you have to vrite to a second csv. If you want to put 2 columns in the second file : old path and new one: replace "echo %1%%~nxa>>filepath_to.csv" with "echo %%a,%1%%~nxa>>filepath_to.csv"

Comment: I think we're still not on the same page - I have two csv files to begin with, and I want to copy the pdf files listed in the first csv file to the locations listed in the second csv file. I'm not trying to create 'filepath_to.csv' but rather trying to read it.

Comment: I don't see any difference in code. The one above should match your criteria either. If filepath_to.csv exists, the content will be appended.

Comment: And there's the difference @mihai_mandis - appending / creating the file is already taken care of. I need the contents of the already existing file to be read and used as the 'to' argument of the xcopy command: `xcopy line_from_filepath_to line_from_filepath_from`.

Comment: So you have to copy PDF files listed in first CSV to the path listed in CSV2? In this case both files have to have the same number of rows. I'll update the code.